# regular expression findall() in Python

Tags: python, regex, match, findall

If I have this string:

```
s = "this, that; talk, love, hate; good, bad, all good."
```

And I want to extract the items separated by , ; or .

So the result I want is:

```
["this", "that", "talk", "love", "hate", "good", "bad", "all good"]
```

If I use this Python regular expression:

```
re.findall(r"([a-z]+[,;.])+", s)
```

I get the result:

```
['this,', 'that;', 'talk,', 'love,', 'hate;', 'good,', 'bad,', 'good.']
```

which is close to what I want, except for the last item.

Strangely, if I include a space in the first square bracket, as in:

```
re.findall(r"([a-z ]+[,;.])+", s)
```

then I only get this result:

```
[' all good.']
```

But findall() is supposed to find all results, no?  Can someone explain this strange behavior?

Comment: `re.split()` may be better for your use case here.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, I can now solve the problem.  But originally I had a confusion about findall(), I thought it returns the different instances of (xyz)+, but it actually tries to find the pattern "afresh" from the last position.  I guess there is no way to make an re return all the instances matched by a "+" ?

Answer (score 3):

Your goal is to split a string into tokens by a separator, so a better way to do this than with `re.findall()` is with [re.split()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split). In this case, you can use

```
>>> re.split(r"[,;.]\s", s)
['this', 'that', 'talk', 'love', 'hate', 'good', 'bad', 'all good.']
```

Unfortunately, this method either puts the period at the end of the last item if you use `[,;.]\s` as the regular expression, and adds an empty string at the end of the result list if you instead use `[,;.]\s?` as the regular expression. We can deal with this, however, by removing the last string:

```
>>> re.split(r"[,;.]\s?", s)[:-1]
['this', 'that', 'talk', 'love', 'hate', 'good', 'bad', 'all good']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookahead:

```
>>> list(re.findall(r"([a-z][a-z ]+(?=[,;.]))+", s))
['this', 'that', 'talk', 'love', 'hate', 'good', 'bad', 'all good']
```

But `re.split()` recommended by @murgatroid99 is better.

Comment: In the example output, he wanted `"all good"` as the last string, not `"good"`, and you dropped the word "all" entirely

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
re.findall(r'[\w\s]+', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` (before close-quote) is outside of the bracket. Put it inside, thus:

```
re.findall(r"\s*([a-z ]+)[ ,;.]+", s)
```

Comment: it will match the whole bracketed expression any number>0 of times

Comment: I don't quite understand the result he gets.. shouldn't that match the whole string?

Comment: `['this,', ' that;', ' talk,', ' love,', ' hate;', ' good,', ' bad,', ' all good.']`. it simply doesn't do the job.

Comment: Sorry, thought that that was what he wanted. Edited to fix.

Comment: This one does not correctly with strings that begin with a space.